# Kivy button press to next page

Tags: class, button, kivy

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class LoginScreen(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2

        self.submit = Button(text='Order', font_size=40)
        self.add_widget(self.submit)
        self.submit.bind(on_press=self.pressed)

    def pressed(self, instance):
        pressing = Secondtab()
        pressing()


class Secondtab(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Secondtab, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 5

        self.submit = Button(text='Drinks', font_size=40)
        self.add_widget(self.submit)

        print('check')

    def __call__(self):
        print('new tab')





class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

So I want the window to change to a new layout when I press the first button. I tought making a new grid class and calling it would work but it didnt work as I expected. I dont want the button to open a new window tho I want the current window to refresh to the new layout.

Comment: Have a look at [ScreenManager](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#module-kivy.uix.screenmanager).

Answer (score 0):

As @John Anderson suggested. Take a look at the [screen manager](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html) widget. The 'current window' must be a populated [screen](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.modules.screen.html) widget and you could change the current screen by assigning the next screen's name to the [current](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager.current) attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you I guess. Using `ScreenManager`:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition

class LoginScreen(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2

        self.submit = Button(text='Order', font_size=40)
        self.add_widget(self.submit)
        self.submit.bind(on_press=self.pressed)

    def pressed(self, instance):
        pressing = Secondtab()
        pressing()
        myapp.screen_manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction='left', duration=.25)    #You can change transition speed or you could just remove it to set it on default
        myapp.screen_manager.current = 'Secondtab'

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()

        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()

        self.loginscreen = LoginScreen()
        screen = Screen(name='LoginScreen')
        screen.add_widget(self.loginscreen)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        self.secondtab = Secondtab()
        screen = Screen(name='Secondtab')
        screen.add_widget(self.secondtab)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        return self.screen_manager
```